# Ember creating model without pushing to store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on creating simple CRUD for model

```
App.ProfilesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set 'content', {}


App.ProfilesNewController = App.ProfilesShowController.extend
  actions:
    cancel: ->
      @transitionToRoute('profiles')

    save: ->
      delete @get('content')["errors"]
      profile = @store.createRecord("profile", @get('content'))
      profile.save().then =>
          console.log("saved")
        ,=>
          console.log("failed")
          @set("content.errors", profile.get("errors"))
          profile.deleteRecord()

form
  .form-group
    label Display Name
    = input value=displayName class="form-control"
    if errors.displayName
      .error
        each errors.displayName
          = this.message
  .form-group
    label Nickname
    = input value=nickname class="form-control"
  .form-group
    label About Me
    = textarea value=info class="form-control"
  .form-group
    label Phone
    = input value=phone class="form-control"
  .form-group
    label Email
    = input value=email class="form-control"

  button click='save' class="btn btn-primary" Save
```

But I dislike this save action. As for me it would be easier to do smt. like

```
App.ProfilesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set 'model', @store.initializeModel("profile")
```

and work with this models without different hooks.
I can't use

```
App.ProfilesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set 'model', @store.createRecord("profile", {})
```

regarding I'm showing list of profiles in left sidebar, and in this case it will appear in this sidebar before being saved.

Will appreciate any advice.

Comment: You can't prevent the record from being added to the store, though you could filter the list of profiles you are displaying by only showing those which don't have `isNew` set. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isNew

Comment: @Leeft  Thank's, yeah, I've tried it, used isDirty for view filtering. But it's too hackish creating new records in store every time I'm visiting /profiles/new page. Maybe anybody has some more clean patterns for "new" records ?

Comment: If you need a base profile to be there then no, that's not "hackish", it's just a bit of memory being allocated (as the store is nothing but a memory cache of things you have retrieved from elsewhere, or you might push elsewhere). Other solutions would require a lot worse in code.